# Reverse map a functional relation(c++)

Tags: c++, function, mapping

I am using a simple function (y(x)), and I want to generate an x value from a certain y value.  While typically reverse mapping does not give a single x value, I am using the maximum from my y values.  This means that there will be a unique x value for the y value I input(the maximum).  I don't understand how to code this in c++

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over all x?

Comment: What kind of function are you talking about? Does it have a closed form inverse?

Comment: C++ is a programming language, not a maths tool. If your function _y_ is given analytically, try a symbolic solver like Maple or Mathematica (or just do the maths yourself). If _y_ is just given numerically, you'll have to write a numeric solver.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have very little background in programming.  I cannot simply use Maple, since I have to iterate this process over 100,000 waveforms(And it is not analytic).  The "function" is actually a set of data, so I am not sure it has a closed form inverse.  Also I am not sure how to iterate over x since it is not quantized(Although I will probably just try to do so with a step of .1 nanosecond or so).

Comment: @Brian: So your question really is something like "I have a 2 place relation that maps X's to Y's.  How do I represent this data in C++ such that I am able to query the inverse relation: given a particular Y, find all the X's that map to it.  In particular, I'm only interested in the maximum such X".  Is that it?

Comment: Will you need to interpolate, or will you only look up values that actually correspond to points _x_?

Comment: @Lambdageek Mostly yes. However I am looking for the X value of the maximum Y.  Since it is a maximum, there will be a single X value that corresponds to it.  I want to find this particular X value.  Right now the data is stored in an hdf5 file, so I  am hoping to be able to use the program on that.

Comment: I do not believe I will need to interpolate it, the actual value is fine.

Comment: @Brian.  Unless your function is injective, there can certainly be multiple X's that map to the same Y.  On the other hand, if you know for a fact that your data always represents an injective function, you will want to store it in a `std::map<Ytype, Xtype>`  where Ytype is the type for your Y data, and Xtype is the type for your X data.

Comment: The data is not injective, however since there is only one global maximum of y, there is only one x value that corresponds to that value.  So I don't think that the code you included will work in this situation.

Comment: Wait, x is not quantized? You mean you don't have a set of discrete x, you have function defined over a *range* of x, and you want to find something close to the maximum? If the function isn't well-behaved, you'll have to just evaluate it at a bunch of closely-spaced points and pick the one that gives the highest value.

Comment: @Brian: Having just one maximum isn't the same as being injective, just consider _y_ (_x_) = - _x_ ^2. But if you basically just have a finite collection of pairs (_x_, _y_) and want to look up _x_ from _y_, consider a `std::map<XType, YType>` iterate over it to find candidate _x_ -values... or even use `std::multimap<YType, XType>` and `equal_range`!

Comment: ....Although, if you are _only_ trying to find the location of the maximum, you can probably do with a simpler loop. Let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need interpolation, only exact reverse lookup, then it's relatively straighforward:

```
std::map<YType, XType> lookup;
// (code to read the file goes here)
// for each x {
    YType y = f(x);
    if ((lookup.count(y) == 0) || (lookup[y] < x)) {
        lookup[y] = x;
    }
// }
```

Then your reverse lookup is just `lookup[y]`, which will return 0 (or a default-constructed value where applicable) if `y` in fact was missing from the data.

Be aware that my code is a bit inefficient, it looks up `y` several times in the map, up to 3. You can optimize using iterators, but I'm concerned that obscures what's going on if you're not already familiar with them:

```
typedef std::map<YType, XType> maptype;
typedef std::pair<maptype::iterator, bool> resulttype;

resulttype result = lookup.insert(std::make_pair(y, x));
if (!result.second) {
    // key already existed, so value was not inserted. Check for max.
    maptype::iterator pos = result.first;
    if ((*pos).second < x) {
        (*pos).second = x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are given a finite range of values *x*, say `x[0]`, `x[1]`, ..., `x[N]`, and a function `f`, and you want to find the index `k` for which `f(x[k])` is the largest possible. In that case, a simple search will do:

```
size_t k = 0;
T m = f(x[k]);
T tmp;

for (size_t i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
{
  if ((tmp = f(x[i])) > m)
  {
    k = i;
    m = tmp;
  }
}

// Maximum is (x[k], m)
```

Here `T` is the type such that `f` is `T f(T);`